# How to get website and customer group list in catalog price rule in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I'm trying to retrieve the website list and customer group list from a record of catalog price rule.

Here what I have done

```
$dataArray = $this->objectManager->create(Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule::class);
$test = $dataArray->getCollection();
$data = $test->getData();
foreach ($data as $value) {
      print_r($value);
}
```

and the data return like this

```
Array ( [row_id] => 29 [rule_id] => 17 [created_in] => 1 [updated_in] => 1613617277 [name] => test tungnt [description] => 123122 [from_date] => 2021-02-18 [to_date] => [is_active] => 0 [conditions_serialized] => {"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":true,"is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all"} [actions_serialized] => {"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Action\\Collection","attribute":null,"operator":"=","value":null} [stop_rules_processing] => 0 [sort_order] => 98 [simple_action] => by_percent [discount_amount] => 30.000000 ) 
Array ( [row_id] => 31 [rule_id] => 18 [created_in] => 1 [updated_in] => 1613618213 [name] => test tun gn t [description] => tunfsd sssss [from_date] => 2021-02-18 [to_date] => [is_active] => 0 [conditions_serialized] => {"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":"1","is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all","conditions":[{"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":"1","is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all","conditions":[{"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"category_ids","operator":"==","value":"5","is_value_processed":false},{"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"attribute_set_id","operator":"==","value":"4","is_value_processed":false}]},{"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"category_ids","operator":"==","value":"6","is_value_processed":false}]} [actions_serialized] => {"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Action\\Collection","attribute":null,"operator":"=","value":null} [stop_rules_processing] => 0 [sort_order] => 98 [simple_action] => by_percent [discount_amount] => 20.000000 )
```

I could not find where website and customer group information to retrieve it like `$value['website']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I found my own solution in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733486/how-to-get-the-customer-group-binded-to-a-sale-rule-in-magento

then my code will be

```
$dataArray = $this->objectManager->create(Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule::class);
$test = $dataArray->getCollection()->load();
foreach ($test as $value) {
      print_r($value->getData('website_ids'));
}
```